# Is it possible to call a .Java file when a button is clicked ? if so how?

Tags: java, class, syntax

Hi I have a JFrame with a menu and an item in its menu. Is it possible to call another my download.java file when that item is clicked ? If so how ? Thanks

download.java

```
     public class download {

     public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

  String fileName = "C:/Users\\Kris\\Downloads\\Death Grips - Get Got.mp3";  
      URL link = new URL("http://www.last.fm/music/Death+Grips/_/Get+Got"); 
     InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(link.openStream());
     ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
     byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
     int n = 0;
     while (-1!=(n=in.read(buf)))
     {
        out.write(buf, 0, n);
     }
     out.close();
     in.close();
     byte[] response = out.toByteArray();

     FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
     fos.write(response);
     fos.close();


     System.out.println("Finished. Your File is Located at"+ fileName );

}
```

}

and from my menu class i need to add an actionListener. But how do I call my download.java file in the action listener is this possible ? Or how can I add my download.java code in the action listener?

```
 download.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
     @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

     //code to download the file??

      }});
```

FINAL ANSWER FOUND MYSELF AFTER THE STRUGGLE OF DOWN VOTING MY QUESTION.

```
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        try {
            download.main(args);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```

This is the way to run a java file from a different file by adding the filename.main(args);

Comment: What do you mean "call a class". What do you mean "start a whole new class"?

Comment: You don't seem to understand what "class" means, which makes it rather hard to understand your question.

Comment: I mean to call my other.java file which downloads the file from the internet when the button is clicked.

Comment: @user3449550: What is `other.java`?  Are you trying to execute an entirely different java process?  Your code should just be able to create an instance of the class and call a method on it (or call a static method without an instance).

Comment: well sorry i am just working too hard it seems i edited my question. i need to call a new file. i.e file1.java has a button in it and when the button is clicked it starts the file2.java

Comment: @David hi, basically I need to create a button which downloads a file from the internet. But I have one file for my java swing layout where i have the menu,items, buttons etc and i need to refer to my download.java file when the button is clicked.

Comment: It's not clear why you think it's impossible. You're "calling" other classes all the time. The ActionListener, the JButton, the JTextArea, the frame, the Strings, they're all other classes from other .java files. Since you're using those without problem, it's not clear why you're stuck.

Comment: @user3449550: You mean something like this?:  `new Download().downloadFile(someFileName);`

Comment: Let me edit my question and maybe it will be more clear. I am sorry for this its just that I have been working on this a lot of time.

Comment: @David hey can you check my question now? many thanks Sir.

Comment: `download.main(null);`

Comment: @user3449550: Does `Download` *need* to be an independently executable class?  That is, do you execute it directly on the command-line by itself elsewhere?  If not, I'd recommend making it a normal object and not putting all the logic in a `main()` method.  If it does need to be executed on its own, I'd recommend extracting the logic into a separate object which both the executable `main()` and the current application can reference.

Comment: Option 1 ->put your download logic in some method inside download class and call that method inside your button click option like new Download().methodName();  option 2) keep the download code directly inside your button action method..option1 is preferable

Answer (score 1):

You have been coding too much PHP. Java doesn't work like that. If what you want to do is call functionality in a different class you can either invoke it directly (if it is static) or create a new object, and invoke the method on that.

To answer your (edited) question there are a few things wrong with your current code. My version is here:

```
public class Download {
    public boolean getFile(String filename, URL link) {
        try (InputStream src = new BufferedInputStream(link.openStream())) {
            try (FileOutputStream dest = new FileOutputStream(filename)) {
                byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                while (true) {
                    int size = src.read(buf);
                    if (size == -1) {
                        break;
                    }
                    dest.write(buf, 0, size);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {
        String fileName = "./Death Grips - Get Got.mp3";
        URL link = new URL("http://www.last.fm/music/Death+Grips/_/Get+Got");
        Download d = new Download();
        if (d.getFile(fileName, link))
        {
            System.out.println("Yay!");
        } else
        {
            System.out.println("Boo!");
        }
    }
}
```

Ok. So an explanation. The main method basically allows you to test that every thing works, and you should delete it from your code. However this is an example of the kind of code you need in your ActionListener. Keep in mind that the URL you are opening is an HTML page, not an mp3 file. Having said that, the rest of the code is pretty self-explanatory, and not significantly functionally different from yours. Just more reusable. :)

Comment: Hi sir thanks for your help and advice. I tried your code and it works the same way as my code. but the problem is what do I have in to my button listener ????

Comment: The code that is in the main method.

Comment: Hey @Mikkel thanks for your reply but it didn't work when I tried to use the code in my listener. You can check in my edited question how I solved the issue that I had to ask in stackoverflow .Thanks for your time.